# How to end selection at an occurrence of a word?

Tags: cursor-motions, selection

Let's say I have this text with `|` as my cursor:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
hi
=======
hello
======
>>>>>> XXXX GGg|
```

Now, I'd like to select from >>>> to say second=== or line containing <<<< word. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in a more general way, you can combine the visual mode with any motion you use in normal mode. That means that you can use `f`, `t`, `w`, etc but you can also use the search:

In your case with your cursor after `GGg` you can start reverse search mode with <kbd>?</kbd> and type `<` in your search prompt. When you type <kbd>Enter</kbd> the end of your selection will end up on the last `<` of the first line. (Maybe linewise visual selection can be useful for you here, it is triggered with <kbd>Shift+v</kbd>.

Note that if you already did the search you can use the motions `n` and `N` to move your visual selection too.

Answer (score 0):

You better be more clear|specific...

> Now, I'd like to select from >>>> to say second===

`Vk`

> or line containing <<<< word. How do I do that?

`Vgg`

And if you want the answer to "How to end selection at an occurrence of a word?"

With the text

```
he|llo beautiful world
```

Where | is your cursor and you want to select till the end of the "beautiful"

`v/ful/e` which is

- `v` visual mode
- `/ful` search for "ful"
- `/e` move cursor to the end of word found

Answer (score 0):

After you enter visual mode (linewise with [`V`](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#linewise-visual) is probably what you want), you can use the [`?`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%3F) to search backwards for the specific string you're looking for.

> I'd like to select from `>>>>` to say second `===`

Use `V`, then `?^======` and press enter.

Use `n` if you want to continue the selection to the first `======` line.

> or line containing `<<<<` word.

Use `V`, then `?^<<<<<<` and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
^va>V
```

- `^` go 1st `>`
- `va>` select [:h a>](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#a%3E) block
- `V` `a>` is characterwise, need to convert to  linewise.

---

Another way is to add `<>` to [:h 'matchpairs'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27matchpairs%27) :

```
set mps+=<:>
```

and do:

```
V^%
```

- `V` start visual linewise
- `^` go to 1st `>`
- `%` goto matching `<` for current `>`.

---

If there are `<` or `>` in the body, add an `e` after `^` to search match for the most outside `>`.

For the `===` part, use `?^===` to search backward, use `n` to repeat last search.